# Header files for STM32F439 timer interrupts

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m, stm32f4

I wrote the following code to program a STM32F439 microcontroller based on the ARM Cortex-M4 processor core. I defined a timer interrupt handler that is triggered every time when TIM7 counts to the end of 1 second so that it executes a specified piece of code every second. The contents of functions InitRCC() (which initialises RCC to enable GPIOs) and ConfGPIO() (which configures GPIO pins) are omitted.

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f439xx.h"
#include "core_cm4.h"
#include "gpioControl.h"

// Configure Timer 7 and automatically start the timer
void ConfTimer7()
{
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM7EN; 
    
    // Reset the peripheral interface
    RCC->APB1RSTR |= RCC_APB1RSTR_TIM7RST;
    
    // Wait a minimum of two clock cycles
    __ASM("NOP");
    __ASM("NOP");
    
    // Clear the reset bit
    RCC->APB1RSTR &= ~(RCC_APB1RSTR_TIM7RST);
    
    // Wait a minimum of two clock cycles
    __ASM("NOP");
    __ASM("NOP");
    
    // Disable Timer 7
    TIM7->CR1 &= ~(TIM_CR1_CEN);
    
    // Clear the prescaler register of Timer 7
    TIM7->PSC &= ~(TIM_PSC_PSC_Msk);
    
    // Set the prescaler value of Timer 7 to 24
    TIM7->PSC |= 2499; // Timer 7 frequency = 42*10^6/(2499+1) = 16.8 kHz
    
    // Clear the auto-reload register of Timer 7
    TIM7->ARR &= ~(TIM_ARR_ARR_Msk);
    
    // Set the count to 16800 (count to 1s)
    TIM7->ARR |= 16800;  
    
    // Set Timer 7 to run in "free-run" mode
    TIM7->CR1 &= ~(TIM_CR1_OPM);
    
    // Enable timer interrupt for Timer 7
    TIM7->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;
    
    // Enable Timer 7
    TIM7->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}

void TIM7_IRQHandler()
{
    
    TIM7->SR &= ~(TIM_SR_UIF); // Clear the timer interrupt flag
    
    // Code to be executed every second
}

int main(void)
{   
    InitRCC();
    ConfGPIO();
    
    // Disable interrupts before configuring the system
    _disable_irq();
    
    // Set the timer interrupt to priority 0
    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM7_DAC_IRQn, 0);
    
    // Configure Timer 7
    ConfTimer7();
    
    // Enable the global interrupt system
    _enable_irq();
   
    while (1)
    {

    }
}
```

When I tried to build the target in Keil µVision 5, the following warnings and errors are shown:

```
src\main.c(526): warning:  #223-D: function "_disable_irq" declared implicitly
    _disable_irq();
src\main.c(529): error:  #20: identifier "TIM7_DAC_IRQn" is undefined
    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM7_DAC_IRQn, 0);
src\main.c(535): warning:  #223-D: function "_enable_irq" declared implicitly
    _enable_irq();
```

How to fix these errors and warnings? Are there any more header files I need to add so that functions `void _enable_irq(void)` and `void _disable_irq(void)` and the identifier "TIM7_DAC_IRQn" are defined? Or is there any alternative to these functions or identifiers in the existing header files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never include  core_cm4.h or stm32f439xx.h directly.

You need to define the correct part number macro STM32F439xx using a command line flag eg: `-DSTM32F439xx`.

After that you should only include `"stm32f4xx.h"`.  This will include the correct CMSIS headers which define `_enable_irq` and `_disable_irq` and all the valid IRQ numbers for the part.

Regarding  TIM7_DAC_IRQn, this is incorrect.  The DAC shares an interrupt with TIM6, and TIM7 has its own separate one.  Chose either `TIM6_DAC_IRQn` or `TIM7_IRQn`.

Comment: Functions ```void _enable_irq(void)``` and ```void _disable_irq(void)``` and the identifier ```TIM7_DAC_IRQn``` are not defined in either stm32f4xx.h or stm32f439xx.h. Are there any alternative functions/identifiers to these that can serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Vector table definitions is in the startup files, not CMSIS. Vector table has to be laced in that particular place in memory so the appropriate linker script is also needed.

To have all of those missed pieces I would rather recommend to use CubeMx, create the project and extract needed files. Linker script, startup files etc etc.